# Subarray counting-help needed

Tags: java, arrays

I was going through a problem on CodeChef (https://www.codechef.com/problems/SUBINC) on counting subarrays which are strictly non-decreasing. Despite reading through the description several times, I was unable to decipher what I was expected to do.

I was mainly having a problem with two statements:

1)*"*All valid subarrays are A[1, 1], A[1, 2], A[2, 2], A[3, 3], A[3, 4], A[4, 4].*"*

If the subarray was 1 4 2 3, then how are A[2,2];A[3,3];A[3,4];and A[4,4] valid?(Given that it is non-decreasing only if forward elements are in decreasing order)Also why is A[1,1] valid?

2)*"Only single subarray A[1, 1] is non-decreasing."*

Similar problem here. If the array itself is only 1 then how can you count A[1,1] is a *sub*-array?

Perhaps I have completely failed to perceive what is to be done as this problem has been solved by many, but a bit of help would really be appreciated.

P.S I code in Java and am not so comfortable in C so that is why I could not understand most of the submissions.

Comment: *how can you count A[1,1] is a sub-array* - Because the instructions say "singleton subarrays are identically non-decreasing"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, you have an array of four numbers
`1 4 2 3`

The notation `A[i, j]` says: "Take all elements of the array from the index `i` to the index `j`".

`A[1,2]` will represent a subarray: `1 4`

`A[1,3]` will represent a subarray: `1 4 2`

`A[1,4]` will be the whole array: `1 4 2 3`

And any single element of the array is a subarray too, 
so when we say `A[1,1]` it means we need to take the elements starting from the index `1` to the index `1`, so it will be just one number: `1`

(`A[2,2]` is `4` therefore and so on).

`Non-decreasing` means that the next element of array must not be less that the previous. So a one-element array is always non-decreasing, the next element in it just doen't exist (so it's can't be less).